# TypeScript Angular: Can you have an (click) event with an object property as its value?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a dynamic error card, with different error messages and with a retry button.

Here is a snippet of my typescript object:

```
errorCard: any = [];
if(error){
     this.errorCard.errorMessage = "oops try again" 
     this.errorCard.buttonFunc = "retry()";
}
```

Now this is my view:

```
  <div class="card-block">
       <div class="card-media-block wrap">
           <div class="card-body">
              <span class="card-media-title">
                  {{errorCard.errorMessage}} // works as expected
              </span>
              ...
            <div class="card-footer"> 
                   //this click is where I would like it to call the function that is tied to that property in this case retry() 
                <button (click)="errorCard.buttonFunc"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i> Retry</button>
            </div>
```

I do not receive any errors in the console with this, and the function does not get triggered.

I thank you guys in advance for your help!

Comment: `this.errorCard.buttonFunc = "retry()";` here `buttonFunc`'s value won't be a function. It would be a `string`. What exactly do you think was supposed to happen?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I was expecting it to reference the function. Do you know a way for me to achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: Where is this `retry` function written? In the same file? And what exactly is this `errorCard`? Is it an `@Input` property that you're getting from somewhere?

Comment: @SiddAjmera this a component that has the .html, .component.ts and the other basic files that get generated

Comment: @SiddAjmera all of the ts is written in the component.ts file, and the template is in the .html file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Component is something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class YourComponent {
  errorCard = {};

  ...

  retry() {
    console.log('Retry Got Called');
  }
}
```

Why don't you simply call the retry method like this(`<button (click)="retry()">Retry</button>`):

```
<div class="card-block">
    <div class="card-media-block wrap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <span class="card-media-title">
        {{errorCard.errorMessage}} // works as expected
      </span>
      ...
      <div class="card-footer"> 
        //this click is where I would like it to call the function that is tied to that property in this case retry() 
        <button (click)="retry()"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i> Retry</button>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Give this [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khcmvq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) a try.